# How can you specify where to create a virtual environment using pipenv?

Tags: python, django, pipenv, virtual-environment

I'm learning django and just installed pipenv via `pip install pipenv` and then `pipenv shell` and I notice that the virtual environment files are installed or created in some random default directory, I have two questions regarding this:

1) How can I customize that installation/creation directory for the virtual environment? Do I have to use a different command line from `pipenv shell`?

2) Can you have multiple folders with different virtual environments inside each folder/project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to the pipenv advanced readme (https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/blob/master/docs/advanced.rst#-custom-virtual-environment-location):

   You can set the environment variable `WORKON_HOME` to whichever directory you want, 
   e.g.: by setting `export WORKON_HOME=~/.venvs` in your .bashrc file (if you are using bash).

---

2. According to this https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/1071#issuecomment-370561179 comment (from the pipenv github repo), you can use a workaround for achieving this:

   > To be super clear, you can still get your own custom environments set
   >   up just by sourcing virtualenvs.
   >
   > ```
   > virtualenv 35 --python=python3.5
   > virtualenv 36 --python=python3.6
   > source 35/bin/activate && pipenv install
   > source 36/bin/activate && pipenv install
   > source 35/bin/activate && pipenv run <whatever>
   > ```
   >
   > a tiny bit of additional visual clutter to the commands but is pretty
   >   straightforward.

   You would execute the `virtualenv x` commands inside the project folder.